# How to show the Tooltip on the JQPlot canvasOverlay?

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I wanted to show some tooltip on the Hover of the canvasOverlay line. After doing some search I got this solution and thought of sharing with others .

```
canvasOverlay: {
        show: true,
         objects: [{
             horizontalLine: {
                 name: 'lineOne',
                 show: true,
                 y: 500,
                 lineWidth: 2,
                 showTooltip: true,
                 tooltipFormatString: 'Actual Target for the Year 2013',
                 xOffset: 0,
                 color: 'rgb(66, 98, 144)',
                 shadow: true
             }
         }]
     }
```

This showTooltip option is not given in the documentations also.

Answer (score 1):

```
canvasOverlay: {
    show: true,
     objects: [{
         horizontalLine: {
             name: 'lineOne',
             show: true,
             y: 500,
             lineWidth: 2,
             showTooltip: true,
             tooltipFormatString: 'Actual Target for the Year 2013',
             xOffset: 0,
             color: 'rgb(66, 98, 144)',
             shadow: true
         }
     }]
 }
```